# Property of the $t$ distribution: $\mathbb{P}(\lim_d t_n \le 1)\neq 0.48.$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I have been working through a probability question, where I am supposed to show that the following claim is **false**

> **Claim:** For each $n$, let $X_n$ follow the $t$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom. Then there exists a distribution $X$ such that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ satisfying $\mathbb{P}(X \le 1)=0.48$.

I know that I am supposed to prove that it is the case that $P(X_n \le 1) \ge 0.5$ which provides a suitable contradiction. However, I am unsure of where to start here. I tried rewriting $X_n$ in terms of variables following the standard normal distribution, however, this seemed to overcomplicate things and not help me to arrive at an answer.

I would be grateful for any guidance here.

Comment: In fact $P(X_1 \le 1)=\frac34$ and $P(X_n \le 1)$ is an increasing function of $n$ with a limit of $\Phi(1) \approx 0.841344746$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $X_n$, we know $\Pr[X_n \le 0] = 0.5$.  This is a property of the symmetry of the Student $t$ distribution about $0$.  So $$\Pr[X_n \le 1] > 0.5 \tag{1} $$ for all $n$.  No consideration of the convergence in distribution is necessary:  *every* choice of $n$ satisfies the property $(1)$ above.